# How to import custom address attribute?

Tags: import, custom-attributes, customer-address, magento2.3

I added this code to my **InstallData** script:

```
     $eavSetup->removeAttribute('customer_address', 'erp_address_system_id');
     $eavSetup->addAttribute(
         'customer_address', 'additional_address_field', [
             'type' => 'text',
             'label' => 'Addtional address field',
             'input' => 'text',
             'required' => false,
             'visible' => true,
             'filterable_in_search' => true,
             'is_visible_on_front' => 0,
             'filterable' => true,
             'system' => 0,
             'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
             'position' => 500,
             'sort_order' => 500
         ]
     );

     $customAttribute = $this->attributeRepository->get('customer_address', 'additional_address_field');
     $setup->getConnection()
         ->insertOnDuplicate(
             $setup->getTable('customer_form_attribute'),
             [
                 ['form_code' => 'adminhtml_customer_address', 'attribute_id' => $customAttribute ->getId()],
             ]
         );
     $customAttribute ->save();
```

When I try to import customer and address data in one file (**entity:** `customer_composite`) and I add the attribute as column `'additional_address_field'` the value is still empty in the backend. When I manually enter a value in the backend the value is stored.

**Why's that? How can I import a custom address attribute?**

Comment: Can you please try this _address_additional_address_field in your csv file header and let me know.?

Comment: I already tried this, but Magento told me that this column is unknown.

Comment: @Jens Add direct additional_address_field, magento will store the value